# How can add line number to richtextbox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox

I am using richtextbox in my app.  The content of richtextbox is combined of regular text and some piece of code different part now have different color background, now i want to put line number beside the code piece like :

```
Some text
1 begin code
2..... 
3.....
4.....
5. End code 

Some other text

1 begin code
2...... 
3.....
4 end code
```

Comment: How are you setting background?  Is the richtextbox editable?

Comment: @blam it is xceed component but i changed. Some part of the source code ;-)  if you need more info please let me know

Comment: Question and comment not clear.

Comment: @blam before i used ICSharpCode https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Syntax-highlighting But i change that to http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com richtextbox. Also i modify some part of the source. Codes.  Imagine it is a editor and i want to show some information the information is combined some c#code and description of code, now code should be have line number like my example above. ;-)

Comment: Is the content of the RichTextBox editable by the user? How are you setting the background different for "code" parts? Couldn't you pre-process the text to contain line numbers in the same manner?